# Error mounting dir from ext4 file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, remote

I am trying to mount a directory on a ext4 type file system onto another linux box. Both boxes are on the same network

```
[root@localhost]# mount -o rw x.y.z.w:/home/lab /devbox
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on x.y.z.w:/home/lab, missing codepage or other error In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so


[root@localhost]# mount -o ro,noload x.y.z.w:/home/lab /devbox
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on x.y.z.w:/home/lab, missing codepage or other error In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so


[root@localhost]# mount -o ro,noload -t ext4 x.y.z.w:/home/lab /devbox
mount: special device x.y.z.w:/home/lab does not exist
```

The dir /home/lab exists on x.y.z.w. Not sure what i am missing here

Answer (score 6):

You need to use some kind of network file system to remotely mount a specific directory. You can't just directly mount a remote directory without any additional software.

1. If you already have ssh running and an account on your remote server use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) 
   `sshfs user@host:/path/to/remote/directory /local/directory`
2. If you already do some network sharing for windows clients just mount the directory via cifs
   `mount -t cifs //server-name/share-name /mnt/cifs`
3. Use [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) to mount the remote directory. You will have to install additional software for rpc on the client and the server and explicitly  configure it to export the device.
   `mount -t nfs -o rw host:/remote/directory /local/directory`

There are other options as well but i think the quickest and simplest solution is just to use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).